# Cant connect to wifi, try connecting and it does nothing

Tags: networking, drivers, 16.04, network-manager, router

First of all i am a beginner, please explain everything you need me to do in detail.
Also, this is a fresh install of ubuntu 16.04 LTS

When i try to connect to my home wifi network it will say connecting for around 15 seconds than go back to how it was. (a connect button).

Thanks!

Edit: sorry for the minute details, just tell me what things to type in terminal or whatever and i can do it. Ty!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ubuntu 16.04 is not stable at 1st release.You should install ubuntu 14.04 and wait for ubuntu 16.04.1 for more stable or use other linux distro.

Comment: Ok im gonna try it